# Export the animation of one bone to .bvh

Tags: export

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to separately export the animation of a single bone into a .bvh file.
I'm currently working on a project with a MakeHuman body, but I only want the motion of the right foot, is this possible? And if so, how?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of your animation, in the dopesheet select all the data you're interested on, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection, <kbd>X</kbd> to delete unecessary data. Export to BVH.